# How to see/get all wall posts of a specific Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

For research purposes I need to get all wall posts of the European Commission's Facebook page. I tried it trough this link, but I couldn't get access: http://graph.facebook.com/EuropeanCommission/posts

Is there any chance I can get a list of all posts ever published by the Commission? Or do I need to hand-copy-and-paste them from the timeline? Comments are not needed.

Comment: If you are copy-pasting, don't use the timeline, instead append "/allactivity" to the page URL. This will actually show you all the posts, as opposed to the timeline, which is filtered through EdgeRank.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just tried in the API Explorer tool and I got the list of posts with pagination links too:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=EuropeanCommission%2Fposts

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "107898832590939_396059463745799",
      "from": {
        "name": "European Commission",
        "category": "Government organization",
        "id": "107898832590939"
      },
      "picture": "http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/523856_348222705225216_107898832590939_963377_101027267_s.jpg",
      "link": "http://www.facebook.com/notes/european-commission/news-update-2-4-march-2012-by-elections-myanmar-conviasa-added-to-eu-blacklist-v/396059463745799",
      "name": "News update 2-4 March 2012: By-elections Myanmar, Conviasa added to EU blacklist, vehicle registration easier and more.",
      "description": "\nMonday 2 April: Catherine Ashton congratulates the Government and people of Myanmar on the conduct of the by-elections\n \n\nMyanmar – Pagodas in Bagan\n \n...",
      "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yY/r/1gBp2bDGEuh.gif",
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment",
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/107898832590939/posts/396059463745799"
        },
        {
          "name": "Like",
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/107898832590939/posts/396059463745799"
        }
      ],
      "type": "link",
      "application": {
        "name": "Notes",
        "id": "2347471856"
      },
      "created_time": "2012-04-04T13:06:58+0000",
      "updated_time": "2012-04-05T07:54:16+0000",
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "EU Law and Publications",
            "category": "Media/news/publishing",
            "id": "218434258171162"
          }
        ],
        "count": 1
      },
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "107898832590939_396059463745799_5180327",
            "from": {
              "name": "Ivan Burrows",
              "id": "1119361344"
            },
            "message": "@ The European Parliament\n\nWhen do we get ours?\n\nIt seems you have finally managed to get an increase in something.\n\n40\u0025 increase in suicides in Greece.\n\nTheir blood is on your hands.\n\nhttp://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-17621131",
            "created_time": "2012-04-05T07:54:16+0000"
          }
        ],
        "count": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "107898832590939_424622557555230",
      "from": {
        "name": "European Commission",
        "category": "Government organization",
        "id": "107898832590939"
      },
      "message": "Marie Therese Vella gets a fresh start thanks to ESF-funded training for people over 40. Have a look at how she did it. Are you planning a career change? Are you currently unemployed? Are you aware of the channels available to you to get help? http://bit.ly/HVaLXZ",
      "picture": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBVJqYwG1_uazFM&w=90&h=90&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fec.europa.eu\u00252Fesf\u00252FBlobServlet\u00253Fmode\u00253DvideoPhoto\u002526videoId\u00253D2491\u002526cnt\u00253D313333967",
      "link": "http://bit.ly/HVaLXZ",
      "name": "Funding - Getting a fresh start",
      "caption": "ec.europa.eu",
      "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment",
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/107898832590939/posts/424622557555230"
        },
        {
          "name": "Like",
          "link": "http://www.facebook.com/107898832590939/posts/424622557555230"
        }
      ],
      "type": "link",
      "created_time": "2012-04-04T11:32:32+0000",
      "updated_time": "2012-04-04T12:24:45+0000",
      "shares": {
        "count": 11
      },
      "likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "Stefanija Stoimenovska",
            "id": "100000025178728"
          }
        ],
        "count": 28
      },
      "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "107898832590939_424622557555230_5762457",
            "from": {
              "name": "Ehtesham Mallick",
              "id": "100001067328472"
            },
            "message": "I wish some training in Laws especially from European countries and prefer training and distance learning about Human rights under the chartered of UNO",
            "created_time": "2012-04-04T12:24:45+0000"
          }
        ],
        "count": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/EuropeanCommission/posts?limit=2&format=json&since=1333544818&__previous=1",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/EuropeanCommission/posts?limit=2&format=json&until=1333539151"
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It worked for me, as well. But the problem is that I only get the posts until 29 March 2012 (see my Screenshot [link](http://kickhiv.de/api.jpg). I need all the posts since the Commission started posting on Facebook in 2010. Any idea how to get them all?

And another question: Can the API Explorer only show the code or also the proper Facebook page?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Here's an example of using the pagination.  `EuropeanCommission/posts?format=json&limit=25&until=1330440566`  You will get items from 2/6/2012 to 2/28/2012.  Please ask that second question as a new Stackoverflow question. Thank you.

Comment: it's giving me only two tags messages and create . no pictures , no stories , no about me nothing else . I have Scopes `user_birthday`, `user_about_me`, `email`, `public_profile`

Comment: Can you do this for a public person like Mark Zuckerburg?

Comment: Give it a try and let us know what you get.